# Cant SSH into Instance Created by OpenStack Cloud

Tags: ssh, openstack

I just launched new Ubuntu 12.04 Instance using Openstack cloud but when i try to SSH into that instance i gotConnection refused.

```
xxx@openstack:$ sudo ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.225 -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.225 [192.168.0.225] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.225 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.225 port 22: Connection refused
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: can you ping your instance??

Answer (score 4):

A connection error like this indicates one of the following issues:

- The instance is not assigned to a security group that has a security rule that opens port 22 for incoming communications. This is the most likely problem.
- There is a firewall on the client machine preventing outgoing access to the remote server on port 22.
- There is a network firewall in the client's network preventing access.

Comment: Trying to enhance the answer a little bit: There is a known problem which results from a misconfiguration of the OpenStack it self. In that case there is an error while the controller tries to inject your ssh key to the newly created VM.